How to convert unicode black pawn emoji to black pawn text character?
I'm making chess in Python 3.12 using purely text for a challenge. The IDE I'm using is Visual Studio 2022. All the other unicode characters, including the white pawn, render as their text character variants fine, but the black pawn renders as an emoji by default. Upon research online, I've discovered this is because the black pawn unicode character as of Unicode 15 is the only one to have an emoji variant. How do I convert to the black pawn text character? Here is my code and the output (for context, liststringify is a function that just turns lists into strings, and the black pieces are white and the white pieces black because the ide uses a black background and uses white text):

thecode
What I tried was using the unicode text codes that are used to find the actual unicode characters, as VS2022 doesn't take just copy and pasting the actual unicode characters in well.
I was expecting no emojis, as I was unaware of the black pawn emoji.
I got the black pawn emoji.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

What function does liststringify have?

@Friedrich: the rule of not uploading images of errors doesn't apply for this question - as it refers to the output unicode rendering itself - the chars used in the error pasted inline here would differ from what the O.P. is getting there.

@EuanG liststringify does as is described in the post. It takes a list, and makes it all just one string.

@jsbueno I think it applies to the image behind the aptly named hyperlink "thecode".

Of course it does. but since this is an edge case, for a newcomer, what can be an image and what cannot is better be described.
As the answer to this ultimatelly does nto depend on the code, I hushed to jst check the output, and negleted the code link  - sorry for that. Now, on to informing the O.P.  (I am writting an answer -  although there are similar questions around here, I see none with an answer which points to the correct way to do it - so I am sketching a few paragraphs as an answer)

Try using another font for output, e.g. DejaVu Sans Mono or Segoe UI Symbol or Unifont or Cascadia Code or Cascadia Mono…

What gets displayed when there is ambiguity in available characters will depend on the combination of (1) The software you are using to display the characters (it can be as diverse as a terminal emulator program, for which there are tens of variants, a browser window, a text-editor like Microsoft Word) and (2)  the font you are using, as configured in the settings or theme of that program.
Unicode however DOES have a mechanism which can go inline with the text you want to display to force emoji or non emoji variants of the characters you want to display.
The problem is that few programs will render correctly the sequence, even if the unicode sequence you send then is unambiguous.
In this case, you should prefix the black pawn character (and preferably all the other chess piece characters, in order to be future-proof) with the U+FE0E (VARIATION SELECTOR-15) character - and, if everything is correctly implemented in the program you are using to display your characters (which, again, might not be the case), should normalize all pieces with their text variants.
If that doesn't work, you can try different variations of the programs you are using to see your output, and, within these programs, configure different font-families, until you find a variation which enables you to work as you want. Actually it may all come down to a single font in your operating system which provides the Black Pawn as emoji - you could have success by simply uninstalling this font, if you can identify it, to have all pieces behaving uniformly across different programs.
Other than that: it is really important when creating questions to stack overflow that the code (And usually the output and error messages) in your question are formatted as part of the question here. This specific case depends on the programming you are using and not on your code, so it was answerable - but typically on answering a question people will want to quote your code to create an improved version, and no one is willing to retype your code).}
Also, taking a look at your code, although your question is not related to it: you would gain a lot, both in file maintainability, which includes ease to perform edits, and ease to write to, size and performance, just use a dictionary instead of this if/elif sequence you created there.
A single dictionary mapping the pieces names to their character is trivial to write in Python as: `pieces = {"WKing": "\u2654", ...}
And then, after the dicionary with as few as 14 entries, you can just do phile.append(f" \ufe0e{pieces[gameboard[i][e]} ") without a single if statement needed.

The ambiguity is in the semantic meaning of the character. As a text character it is a black pawn piece, as an emoji it is represents not the chess piece, rather it represents the game of chess. Without a VS16 character it should be displayed as text. It is possible the underlying issue is font fallback. The best way to test this is running the code on multiple platforms.

As I mentioned in the text, in my experience very few applications, library or platform implement correctly some of the subtle aspects of Unicode.
In this case, however, I always ever got the pawn as text, across several terminal emulator programs (I don't remember have ever trying it on Windows, though)

And many like Python also have problems with the gross aspects of Unicode, and not just the subtle. Although in this instance I suspect that it is a font fallback issue, but without more precise details the best we can come up with are approximate answers. VS15 might solve his problem, or may make no difference.
